# How to find Strongly Connected Components in a Graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, strongly-connected-graph

I am trying self-study Graph Theory, and now trying to understand how to find [SCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) in a graph. I have read several different questions/answers on SO (e.g., [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182766/i-can-not-really-understand-how-the-strongly-connected-component-algorithm-works),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086778/what-if-i-do-not-use-g-transpose-in-calculating-strongly-connected-components),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764583/finding-strongly-connected-components-in-a-graph-through-dfs),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364269/strongly-connected-components-find-the-finishing-time),[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093690/finding-strongly-connected-components),[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275237/finding-strongly-connected-subgraphs-in-a-graph?rq=1),[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033343/finding-the-strongly-connected-components-in-a-di-graph-in-one-dfs?rq=1),[8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434787/algorithm-to-check-if-directed-graph-is-strongly-connected?rq=1)), but I cant find one with a complete step-by-step example I could follow.

According to [CORMEN (Introduction to Algorithms)](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms), one method is:

> 1. Call DFS(G) to compute finishing times f[u] for each vertex u
> 2. Compute Transpose(G)
> 3. Call DFS(Transpose(G)), but in the main loop of DFS, consider the vertices in order of decreasing f[u] (as computed in step 1)
> 4. Output the vertices of each tree in the depth-first forest of step 3 as a separate strong connected component

Observe the following graph (question is 3.4 from [here.](http://beust.com/algorithms.pdf) I have found several solutions [here](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~goldsd/docs/spring2013-csci2300/hw2-solns.txt) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/markdolanprogramming/cis-3223/assignment-5), but I am trying to break this down and understand it myself.)

[image]

**Step 1: Call DFS(G) to compute finishing times f[u] for each vertex u**

*Running DFS starting on vertex A:*

[image]

Please notice RED text formatted as [Pre-Vist, Post-Visit]

**Step 2: Compute Transpose(G)**

[image]

**Step 3.  Call DFS(Transpose(G)), but in the main loop of DFS, consider the vertices in order of decreasing f[u] (as computed in step 1)**

Okay, so vertices in order of decreasing post-visit(finishing times) values:

{E, B, A, H, G, I , C, D, F ,J}

So at this step, we run DFS on G^T but start with each vertex from above list:

- DFS(E): {E}
- DFS(B): {B}
- DFS(A): {A}
- DFS(H): {H, I, G}
- DFS(G): remove from list since it is already visited
- DFS(I): remove from list since it is already visited
- DFS(C): {C, J, F, D}
- DFS(J): remove from list since it is already visited
- DFS(F): remove from list since it is already visited
- DFS(D): remove from list since it is already visited

**Step 4: Output the vertices of each tree in the depth-first forest of step 3 as a separate strong connected component.**

So we have five strongly connected components: {E}, {B}, {A}, {H, I, G}, {C, J, F, D}

### *This is what I believe is correct. However, solutions I found [here](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~goldsd/docs/spring2013-csci2300/hw2-solns.txt) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/markdolanprogramming/cis-3223/assignment-5) say SCCs are {C,J,F,H,I,G,D}, and {A,E,B}. Where are my mistakes?*

Comment: Look a `B` and `E`: both have an indegree of zero and form a (degenerate) SCC all by themselves. I think the linked answers to be wrong. (beat me by 40 secs.)

Comment: I believe the answers given in the sources you provide are wrong although both implementations are correct. I have implemented the algorithm that they are using and my algorithm gives me the answer you reached to. I guess they've comitted a mistake some where, but the algorithm isn't wrong. neither yours nor theirs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your steps are correct and your answer is also correct, by examining the other answers you provided you can see that they used a different algorithm: First you run DFS on G transposed and then you run an undirected components algorithm on G processing the vertices in decreasing order of their post numbers from the previous step.

The problem is they ran this last step on G transposed instead of in G and thus got an incorrent answer. If you read Dasgupta from page 98 onwards you will see a detailed explanation of the algorithm they (tried) to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your answers is correct. As per CLRS, "A strongly connected component of a directed graph G = (V,E) is a maximal set of vertices C, such that for every pair of vertices u and v, we have both u ~> v and v ~> u, i.e. vertices v and u are reachable from each other."

In case you assume {C, J, F, H, I, G, D} as correct, there is no way to reach from D to G (amongst many other fallacies), and same with other set, there is no way to reach from A to E.