# giving the paired nodes and a list of random nodes, find and group the nodes that are connected in python

Tags: python, graph-theory

saying I have a list of pairs like
`pairs = [[0,10],[0,1],[0,2],[1,7],[2,3],[2,4],[3,8],[4,5],[5,6],[8,9]]`
and a list
`a = [3,4,5,6,8,9]`.
Based on given pairs, how to group list, a, into `[[3,8,9],[4,5,6]]`? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the Wikipedia artivle on graph components.  It has everything you need. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find Strongly Connected Components in a Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590974/how-to-find-strongly-connected-components-in-a-graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [networkx](/questions/tagged/networkx) for this, with the [`subgraph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html) and [`connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html) methods:

```
import networkx as nx

pairs = [[0,10],[0,1],[0,2],[1,7],[2,3],[2,4],[3,8],[4,5],[5,6],[8,9]]
a = [3,4,5,6,8,9]

G = nx.from_edgelist(pairs)

out = list(nx.connected_components(G.subgraph(a)))
```

Output:  `[{3, 8, 9}, {4, 5, 6}]`